# How to use 2 Labels in one Conditional tag in Blogger

Tags: conditional-statements, blogger

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "Label"'>
<style type='text/css'>
.foa_bg {
  background-image: url(https://site.io/images/covers/image.jpg);
}
</style>
</b:if>
```

I wold like to have in one line 2 or 5 labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` operator

```xml
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel in ["Label1","Label2","Label3"]'>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .foa_bg {
       background-image: url(https://site.io/images/covers/image.jpg);
    }
  </style>
</b:if>
```